# Distribution of p under alternative hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose $X_{i}...X_{n}$ are i.i.d Bernoulli with $P_{\theta}(X_{i} = 1) = \theta = 1 - P_{\theta}(X_{i} = 0)$.

n is large. Consider testing $H_{0} = 0.5$ versus $H_{1} : \theta > 0.5.$

Let $\hat \theta_{n} = \sum \frac{X_{i}}{n}$ be the MLE of $\theta$. Consider the large sample test which rejects when $2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - 0.5) > z_{1-\alpha}$, where $z_{1-\alpha}$ is the 1 - $\alpha$ quantile of the standard normal distribution.

> (i) An approximate p-value can be computed as the area under the normal curve to the right of $2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - 0.5)$. We can define the p-value $\hat  p_{n}$ by  $1 - \Phi[2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - 0.5)]$. Where $\Phi$ denotes that standard normal distribution. If $H_{0}$ is true, what is the limiting distribution of $\hat p_{n}$?

Here is what I believe I know if $H_{0}$ is true:

$2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - 0.5)$ $\xrightarrow{d}$ N(0,1)   (MLE asymptotic normality)

$\therefore$ $\hat p_{n}$ $\xrightarrow{d}$ U[0,1]

If $H_{a}$ is true, here is what I have gotten (Where $\theta_{1}$ is the $H_{a}$ parameter and $\theta_{0}$ is the $H_{0}$ parameter):

$2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - (0.5 + \theta_{1} - \theta_{0})$  $\xrightarrow{d}$ N(0,1)

$\therefore$ $2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - 0.5)$ $\xrightarrow{d}$ N($2\sqrt{n}(\theta_{1} - \theta_{0}),1)$

If Z = $2\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{n} - (0.5 + \theta_{1} - \theta_{0}))$, then:

P(Z $\geq z_{1-\alpha} - 2 \sqrt{n}(\theta_{1} - \theta_{0})$)

If $n \rightarrow \infty$, then the probability tends to one.

I don't believe this is right. The $\hat p_{n}$ should be skewed towards $0$ because p values are likelier to be significant, but I am not sure where I am wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any ideas....anyone? 

I’m trying to see which step I butchered. Please let me know if I can provide additional information/steps.

Comment: What is $\hat{p}_n$?

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't know how I missed to include that info. I made the edit in the block quote, thanks!